# Why does Pandas calculate the variance using not the full length of the population

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why does Pandas use in the variance calculation not the size of the population, but the size of the population minus 1?

Example:

```
content_agg = train_df.groupby('content_id')[target].agg(['sum', 'count', 
                               lambda x : ((x - x.mean()) ** 2).sum() / (len(x) -1), 
                               'var'])
```

The lambda expression emulates what Pandas seems to be doing, since the lambda result and the Pandas variance are the same. I see these results in a Jupyter notebook:

[image]

If I now use the full population (`len(x)`) in the lambda function, like so:

```
train_df.groupby('content_id')[target].agg(['sum', 'count', 
                              lambda x : ((x - x.mean()) ** 2).sum() / (len(x)), 
                              'var'])
```

[image]

The result of the lambda and the calculated variance are obviously not the same.

What are the reasons to use not the full length of the population in Pandas for the variance calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance . Wikipedia has good coverage of the question

You can change the behavior of pandas Var function by ddof argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the `ddof` parameter. Can you use it with the `agg` function?

Comment: you can send it as a kwarg: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html @gil.fernandes